# operation count for computing the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ directly is $O(n!)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am looking for some help with the following question. I have some ideas below but I am not quite sure how to execute this answer.

> Show  that  the  operation  count  for  computing  the  determinant  of  an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ directly is $O(n!)$ and thus for large $n$ significantly worse than using the LU
>   factorization.

If we denote $d_n$ the number of operations - additions and multiplications - required to calculate an $n \times n$ determinant by the way of cofactor expansion. For example a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A = a_{ij}$

$$detA = a_{11}(a_{22})-a_{12}(a_{21})$$

Hence, two multiplications and one addition are necessary, and so $d_2 = 3$

This is just an example of a case, but how do I prove my question generally?

Comment: The constant function $f(n) = 11$ is $O(n!)$, but that doesn't make it worse than the cost of the LU-version of computing determinants. To make that conclusion, you need to show that the op-count you care about is actually $\Omega(n!)$ [or, as I prefer to put it, that it actually lies in $\Omega(n \mapsto n!)$].  Perhaps the person who posed the question needs to review the definition of big-$O$.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks for the comment, yes I will have to review this concept, would you be able to show me how my question is proven?

Comment: No. no...I meant that the person who asked YOU this question (your professor or TA perhaps) might need to review. In the meantime, I cannot give a proof to the claim you've asked about, because, as written, it's false.

Comment: @JohnHughes oh I thought you meant me, I was confused. Could you show me what you were explaining in your comment above of what it should be?

Comment: should it be $O(n \cdot n!) $ like mentioned below?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you define the determinant via

$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\bigg(sgn(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^nA_{i,\sigma(i)}\bigg)$$

So the inner product

$$\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i, \sigma(i)}$$

does exactly $n$ multiplications. Multiplying by $sgn(\sigma)$ is $O(1)$ so all in all

$$O\bigg(sgn(\sigma)\prod A_{i, \sigma(i)}\bigg)=O(n)$$

for a fixed $\sigma$. I also assume that calculating $sgn(\sigma)$ is $O(1)$. Now $S_n$ has exactly $n!$ elements so

$$O\bigg(\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}sgn(\sigma)\prod A_{i, \sigma(i)}\bigg)=O\bigg(\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}n\bigg)=O\bigg(n\cdot\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}1\bigg)=O(n\cdot n!)$$

which finally gives $O(n\cdot n!)$, not $O(n!)$.

Although I didn't prove that it is not $O(n!)$ (see: [the big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ) it actually is not $O(n!)$ because $\det(A)$ does precisely $n!\cdot(n+1)$ arithmetic operations (I ignore the fact that you have to generate the set of all permutations $S_n$ because it can be done in $O(n!)$) by the former argumentation. The $n!$ comes from summation over $S_n$, the $n$ from inner $\prod$ product and $+1$ from multiplying by $sgn(\sigma)$. Or in other words $\det(A)$ is $\Theta(n\cdot n!)$ - [the big-Theta notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).

Also note the problem with the big-O notation: constant function is $O(n!)$. Does it mean it is slow? No. Whoever gave you the exercise most likely meant some other growth describing notation, e.g. the big-Theta.

Comment: could you show how you sum everything to get this result?

Comment: @mt12345 How about now?

Comment: thanks, so thos shows the operation count for computing the determinant of an $ n \times n$ matrix A is $O(n \cdot n!)$?

Comment: instead of $O(n!)$? as the question asked, which may have been a mistake by the questioner?

Comment: @mt12345 Yes, this seems like a mistake in the question. Unless there's some other definition of $\det(A)$ used.

Comment: I'd suggest that the most common definition (in US schools, anyhow) is expansion by cofactors. You multiply $a_{1i}$ by the determinant of the matrix produced by removing the first row and $i$th column; you then compute an alternating sum of these over all $i$. That's $n$ times the work of doing an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ determinant, which by induction, is proportional to $(n-1)!$. Hence the total work is in $\Theta(n!)$. [I've omitted most details, but the gist is there...]